# Change parent component height style when load child component in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I need to load child component in parent component,child component has an element with *ngIf 
with variable "show" that equal false, in the first it doesn't shown then by click on a button in child component "show" will has true value
But when "show" become true, parent height doesn't change 
How can I change parent height after book is loaded?

```
<div id="parent">
   <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

child component template:

```
<div>
 ...somthing
 <div *ngIf="show" id="book"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a stackbiltz sample

Comment: what do you mean by `parent height`?

Comment: please add more clarity.

Comment: Why dont you make height: 100% for parent and try ?

Comment: parent element height style,it doesn't change

Comment: height:100% doesn't work-@PrashantPimpale

Comment: when i load child component into parent component in the first show=false and book element doesn't exsit in dom, then I click on a button show=true and book will be shown it change child component height style but parent component height style doesn't change and child element grows from the bottom and passes through the parent

Comment: Is the parent display: block?

Comment: No, it isn't block, i try it but didn't solved-@Yin